# Can't inject IWebHostEnvironment in Azure Durable Funciton

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure Durable Function and want to use IWebHostEnvironment. But when I try to inject it into the HttpStart function or my orchestrator I get the error:
Cannot bind parameter 'env' to type IWebHostEnvironment. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. I have not been able to find examples with Durable Functions and IWebHostEnvironment.

What I am trying to do is the equivalent of Server.MapPath(), which is not available in n.et core.

Comment: I believe there is no support for `IWebHostEnvironment` in Azure Functions but for the temporary workaround, you can create your own `IFunctionsHostEnvironment` interface that returns result based on the value of `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT")`, which is automatically set to Development locally by Core Tools and can be set manually in Azure portal.

Comment: Thanks @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT, this got me going in the right direction. I have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble was that I was not getting errors but could not see the files in Kudo. They I found a post saying to set WEBSITE_DISABLE_SCM_SEPARATION = true, allowing Kudu to see the current process. Makes perfect sense after I thought about it for a moment.

Reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/788799/where-are-my-azure-temp-files